# Multiprocessing.Pool.map returns wrong values

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to compute this `for loop`:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial


def main():

    nodes = 53
    f_nom = 50
    U = [1.000005327453146, 1.0000057162412561, 1.0000070448192537, 1.0000069227537496, 1.0000069227537496, 1.0000041605235332, 1.0000035222393044, 1.000004263922246, 1.0000047513736152, 1.0000047550593771, 1.0000049581713173, 1.000004263922246, 1.0000039401443763, 1.0000026446387185, 1.0000014323088564, 1.0000026446387185, 1.0000036287590721, 1.0000026446387185, 1.0000039401443768, 1.0000014323088589, 1.0000039401443768, 1.0000014323088553, 1.0000014323088553, 1.0000030231390993, 1.0000014323088615, 1.0000014323088615, 1.0000014323088606, 1.0000014323088604, 1.0000014323088597, 1.0000014323088606, 1.0000014323088604, 1.0000014323088597, 1.0000014323088593, 1.000001432308859, 1.000001432308858, 1.000001590333777, 1.0000020451347542, 1.000001432308861, 1.0000014323088602, 1.000001432308863, 1.00000143230886, 1.000001432308859, 1.000001432308863, 1.000001432308863, 1.000001432308859, 1.000001432308863, 1.00000143230886, 1.0000014323088615, 1.000001432308859, 1.0000014323088615, 1.0000057853629756, 1.0000059478472048, 1.0000000056539258, 1.0]
    theta = [-7.355656043185493e-06, -3.464594992534604e-06, -1.0583594144863342e-05, -9.626585410799617e-06, -9.626585410799618e-06, -5.6945086783273145e-06, -2.674752704682853e-06, -5.841699103904964e-06, -6.535596440474819e-06, -3.118569281977461e-06, -6.829976913326792e-06, -5.841699103904964e-06, -2.825199109428268e-06, -2.3588148383740883e-06, -1.1617097845584577e-06, -2.3588148383740883e-06, -4.937528901600708e-06, -2.3588148383740883e-06, -2.8251991094452968e-06, -1.1617097837371578e-06, -2.8251991094452976e-06, -1.1617097849706262e-06, -1.1617097849706262e-06, -4.075412032614385e-06, -1.1617097820641042e-06, -1.1617097820641045e-06, -1.16170978206629e-06, -1.161709782064495e-06, -1.1617097822154165e-06, -1.16170978206629e-06, -1.161709782064495e-06, -1.1617097822154165e-06, -1.1617097834417375e-06, -1.1617097836565141e-06, -1.1617097839483619e-06, -2.0357655204310186e-06, -1.766840164692082e-06, -1.1617097820892918e-06, -1.1617097821105786e-06, -1.1617097821630116e-06, -1.1617097822743808e-06, -1.1617097836888828e-06, -1.161709782163012e-06, -1.1617097821630119e-06, -1.1617097836179758e-06, -1.1617097821630119e-06, -1.1617097822743808e-06, -1.1617097820641042e-06, -1.161709783617976e-06, -1.1617097820641047e-06, -8.007497618793153e-06, -8.238796094878206e-06, -1.972012101284986e-08, 0.0]
    U_start = [396.98922, 397.590444, 396.6735, 396.663384, 396.625768, 397.134352, 397.85536, 397.132184, 397.123008, 397.680784, 397.074752, 397.131104, 397.78544, 397.975768, 397.642204, 398.124984, 397.186264, 397.87854, 397.766736, 397.505908, 397.706156, 397.640524, 397.643368, 397.294984, 397.816152, 397.855528, 397.792792, 397.785664, 397.736036, 397.802636, 397.783008, 397.746864, 397.641188, 397.56948, 397.635652, 397.676168, 397.972024, 397.835444, 397.76222, 397.440376, 397.740988, 397.405996, 397.40994, 397.429992, 397.336748, 397.466372, 397.744532, 397.846052, 397.311572, 397.728728, 396.841804, 396.767284, 397.679944, 400.]
    t = np.linspace(0, 0.1, int(0.1 * 20000), dtype=np.float64)
    wave_line = np.zeros((3, nodes, len(t)))
    wave_line_mp = np.zeros((3, nodes, len(t)))
    looprange = 5

    for i in range(looprange):
        harm_order = i + 2
        for n in range(nodes):
            U_line = cmath.polar(cmath.rect(1.0, 0.0) - cmath.rect(U[n], theta[n]))
            wave_line[0, n] += np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(3) * U_line[0] * U_start[n] * np.sin((t * 2 * np.pi * f_nom + U_line[1]) * harm_order)
            wave_line[1, n] += np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(3) * U_line[0] * U_start[n] * np.sin((t * 2 * np.pi * f_nom + U_line[1] - 2 / 3 * np.pi) * harm_order)
            wave_line[2, n] += np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(3) * U_line[0] * U_start[n] * np.sin((t * 2 * np.pi * f_nom + U_line[1] + 2 / 3 * np.pi) * harm_order)

        print(i, wave_line[0][0][0])
        wave_line[:] = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output 1:

```
0 -0.0027971102683270466
1 0.000897146546025977
2 0.0017446246602729246
3 -0.0029438493445009956
4 0.0017089460869939772
```

in a `multiprocessing.Pool.map` function:

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial


def main():

    nodes = 53
    f_nom = 50
    U = [1.000005327453146, 1.0000057162412561, 1.0000070448192537, 1.0000069227537496, 1.0000069227537496, 1.0000041605235332, 1.0000035222393044, 1.000004263922246, 1.0000047513736152, 1.0000047550593771, 1.0000049581713173, 1.000004263922246, 1.0000039401443763, 1.0000026446387185, 1.0000014323088564, 1.0000026446387185, 1.0000036287590721, 1.0000026446387185, 1.0000039401443768, 1.0000014323088589, 1.0000039401443768, 1.0000014323088553, 1.0000014323088553, 1.0000030231390993, 1.0000014323088615, 1.0000014323088615, 1.0000014323088606, 1.0000014323088604, 1.0000014323088597, 1.0000014323088606, 1.0000014323088604, 1.0000014323088597, 1.0000014323088593, 1.000001432308859, 1.000001432308858, 1.000001590333777, 1.0000020451347542, 1.000001432308861, 1.0000014323088602, 1.000001432308863, 1.00000143230886, 1.000001432308859, 1.000001432308863, 1.000001432308863, 1.000001432308859, 1.000001432308863, 1.00000143230886, 1.0000014323088615, 1.000001432308859, 1.0000014323088615, 1.0000057853629756, 1.0000059478472048, 1.0000000056539258, 1.0]
    theta = [-7.355656043185493e-06, -3.464594992534604e-06, -1.0583594144863342e-05, -9.626585410799617e-06, -9.626585410799618e-06, -5.6945086783273145e-06, -2.674752704682853e-06, -5.841699103904964e-06, -6.535596440474819e-06, -3.118569281977461e-06, -6.829976913326792e-06, -5.841699103904964e-06, -2.825199109428268e-06, -2.3588148383740883e-06, -1.1617097845584577e-06, -2.3588148383740883e-06, -4.937528901600708e-06, -2.3588148383740883e-06, -2.8251991094452968e-06, -1.1617097837371578e-06, -2.8251991094452976e-06, -1.1617097849706262e-06, -1.1617097849706262e-06, -4.075412032614385e-06, -1.1617097820641042e-06, -1.1617097820641045e-06, -1.16170978206629e-06, -1.161709782064495e-06, -1.1617097822154165e-06, -1.16170978206629e-06, -1.161709782064495e-06, -1.1617097822154165e-06, -1.1617097834417375e-06, -1.1617097836565141e-06, -1.1617097839483619e-06, -2.0357655204310186e-06, -1.766840164692082e-06, -1.1617097820892918e-06, -1.1617097821105786e-06, -1.1617097821630116e-06, -1.1617097822743808e-06, -1.1617097836888828e-06, -1.161709782163012e-06, -1.1617097821630119e-06, -1.1617097836179758e-06, -1.1617097821630119e-06, -1.1617097822743808e-06, -1.1617097820641042e-06, -1.161709783617976e-06, -1.1617097820641047e-06, -8.007497618793153e-06, -8.238796094878206e-06, -1.972012101284986e-08, 0.0]
    U_start = [396.98922, 397.590444, 396.6735, 396.663384, 396.625768, 397.134352, 397.85536, 397.132184, 397.123008, 397.680784, 397.074752, 397.131104, 397.78544, 397.975768, 397.642204, 398.124984, 397.186264, 397.87854, 397.766736, 397.505908, 397.706156, 397.640524, 397.643368, 397.294984, 397.816152, 397.855528, 397.792792, 397.785664, 397.736036, 397.802636, 397.783008, 397.746864, 397.641188, 397.56948, 397.635652, 397.676168, 397.972024, 397.835444, 397.76222, 397.440376, 397.740988, 397.405996, 397.40994, 397.429992, 397.336748, 397.466372, 397.744532, 397.846052, 397.311572, 397.728728, 396.841804, 396.767284, 397.679944, 400.]
    t = np.linspace(0, 0.1, int(0.1 * 20000), dtype=np.float64)
    wave_line = np.zeros((3, nodes, len(t)))
    wave_line_mp = np.zeros((3, nodes, len(t)))
    looprange = 5

    func_part = partial(worker_function, nodes=nodes, f_nom=f_nom, U=U, theta=theta, U_start=U_start, t=t, wave_line_mp=wave_line_mp)
    wave_line_results = mp.Pool(1).map(func_part, range(looprange))

    print('')
    for idx, wave_line_mp in wave_line_results:
        print(idx, wave_line_mp[0][0][0])


def worker_function(i=None, nodes=None, f_nom=None, U=None, theta=None, U_start=None, t=None, wave_line_mp=None):
    harm_order = i + 2
    wave_line_mp[:] = 0
    for n in range(nodes):
        U_line = cmath.polar(cmath.rect(1.0, 0.0) - cmath.rect(U[n], theta[n]))
        wave_line_mp[0, n] += np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(3) * U_line[0] * U_start[n] * np.sin((t * 2 * np.pi * f_nom + U_line[1]) * harm_order)
        wave_line_mp[1, n] += np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(3) * U_line[0] * U_start[n] * np.sin((t * 2 * np.pi * f_nom + U_line[1] - 2 / 3 * np.pi) * harm_order)
        wave_line_mp[2, n] += np.sqrt(2) / np.sqrt(3) * U_line[0] * U_start[n] * np.sin((t * 2 * np.pi * f_nom + U_line[1] + 2 / 3 * np.pi) * harm_order)

    print(i, wave_line_mp[0][0][0])

    return i, wave_line_mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output 2:

```
0 -0.0027971102683270466
1 0.000897146546025977
2 0.0017446246602729246
3 -0.0029438493445009956
4 0.0017089460869939772

0 0.000897146546025977
1 0.000897146546025977
2 -0.0029438493445009956
3 -0.0029438493445009956
4 0.0017089460869939772
```

As you can see output (2.1) inside the `worker_function` is correct (it is similar to the above output (1) of the for loop) while the returned `wave_line_results` and thus output (2.2) is not. There seems to be a value overlap, maybe a scheduling problem with the `Pool` function?

Comment: You seem to be passing in a mutable argument and then changing it. Maybe you want to make a copy?

Comment: Works for me if I put `wave_line_mp = wave_line_mp.copy()` at the start of `worker_function` - although of course it then overwrites the values with zeros, so maybe you could just create the array of zeros inside the worker function, based on the shape, and not pass in the array at all.

Comment: Welp, looks like you have resolved my problem in a few minutes. Do you want to post an answer :-) ?

Comment: Okay, have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemt that you are passing the (mutable) array `wave_line_mp` into the function and then changing it, and that you should be operating on separate copies of it in order to do so. A simple one-line fix is to insert `wave_line_mp = wave_line_mp.copy()` at the start of `worker_function`, but a better solution is probably to remove it from the argument list of the function entirely (and of course also from where it is called), and move the line:

```
    wave_line_mp = np.zeros((3, nodes, len(t)))
```

from inside `main` to the start of `worker_function`.  (This works because the variables `nodes` and `t` are passed through to variables of the same names inside `worker_function`.)  You would also remove the line `wave_line_mp[:] = 0`, which is then redundant.

Doing this, you get the desired output:

```
0 -0.00279711026833
1 0.000897146546026
2 0.00174462466027
3 -0.0029438493445
4 0.00170894608699

0 -0.00279711026833
1 0.000897146546026
2 0.00174462466027
3 -0.0029438493445
4 0.00170894608699
```